# Magento2: Category URL rewrite issue

Tags: magento2, category, import

I am trying to import product from magento but when I try import I will get below errors.

I have flushed all category then update the new category. Got the error message below:

```
General system exception happened
Additional data: URL key for the specified store already exists.
```

Please help me with this.

Comment: There is already one more category with the same key. please check it and delete it. share screenshot.

Comment: How can I remove the same key from the database? @sarveshDineshkumarPatel

Comment: ok, first check categories are in admin or not? please share screenshot so I will get better idea.

Comment: Ok i will share screenshot.

Comment: 1) https://ibb.co/GQd6N5w
2) https://ibb.co/4RnPz3C @sarveshDineshkumarPatel

Comment: so it is an issue with import products right?

Comment: Yes, It is right @sarveshDineshkumarPatel

Comment: please share me that import files on that base I can check and update you.

Comment: so the issue is in your CSV file bro.

Comment: please download that report and check instructions.

Comment: https://docdro.id/5JFfQOi Please find the link @sarveshDineshkumarPatel

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/102241/discussion-between-masud-shaikh-and-sarvesh-dineshkumar-patel).

Comment: Please check the comment on chat @sarveshDineshkumarPatel

Answer (score 1):

My issue is resolved when I truncate the **url_rewrite** table from the database.

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0;
TRUNCATE TABLE `url_rewrite`; 
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 1;
```